# Using data generated from a hook in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In sails.js, can a service use data or functions generated by a hook or by `sails.config.bootstrap`?
Or it's only the other way around?

EDIT: I was trying to add a hook to set up my rate limiter's parameters before `sails lift`, and then use this rate limiter from within the application.

Comment: Services is loading at the stage when sails is not global object. So you can't do this...

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to do...

Comment: @sgress454 Added a bit more of background.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap file in `config/bootstrap.js` is intended mainly for setting up data, jobs, etc. that are specific to your app and may need to run only once.  It's run after all of your models, services and hooks have already loaded, so it can rely on them.

You can use a hook method inside of a service method--you just can't use it to *set up* a service.  So, this is okay:

```
// config/services/GoodService.js
module.exports = {
  someMethod: function() {
    var rateLimit = sails.hooks.someHook.getRateLimit();        
  }
};
```

This is not okay:

```
// config/services/BadService.js
var rateLimit = sails.hooks.someHook.getRateLimit();
module.exports = {
  someMethod: function() {...do something with rateLimit...}
}
```